# How do I solve this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have 2 curves of the form Y = X^3 *PF (different values of PF for each curve), the second is rotated by 180 degrees and I would like to find values of X for each curve such that they meet with the same slope and sum to a certain value.

The first bit is easy:
Ya = Xa^3 * PFa
Yb = Xb^3 * PFb
I would like them to sum to ReqSpeed, so Ya+Yb = ReqSpeed, so (Xa^3 * PFa)  + (Xb^3 * PFb) = ReqSpeed

I can rearrange this to 
Xa =   ((ReqSpeed -(Xb^3 * PFb))  /    PFa)^1/3

For the slopes: (differentiate the equation above):
Slopea = 3*Xa^2 *PFa
Slopeb = 3*Xb^2 *PFb
and the slopes are the same so 3*Xa^2 *PFa = 3*Xb^2 *PFb
(3s cancel) Xa^2 *PFa = Xb^2 *PFb
Xa^2 = Xb*PFb/PFa
Xa = (Xb*PFb/PFa)^1/2

So I have 2 equations for Xa, one relating to the total height and one to the slope. So If I put them together, I should get an equation for Xb:

((ReqSpeed -(Xb^3 * PFb))  /    PFa)^1/3    =    (Xb*PFb/PFa)^1/2

Unfortunately I don't know how to solve this for Xb! Can anyone help? Or is my approach wrong? Many Thanks

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ to format your question.

Comment: I did not check your approach but if you want to post the values of the parameters, I shall show you.

Comment: I can work it out if I know the values of the parameters, but they too are variables so I need a general equation for Xb from all the other parameters

Answer (score 1):

Please use $\LaTeX$ to make it clear for people to read.

If I understand your equation good. It looks like this one:

$(\frac{a-bx^3}{c})^{1/3}=(\frac{bx}{c})^{1/2}$ where $a=$ReqSpeed, $b=$PFb, $c=$PFa, and $x=$Xb.

Now make the equation to the power 6 you will get:

$(\frac{a-bx^3}{c})^{6/3}=(\frac{bx}{c})^{6/2}$ or equivalently, $(\frac{a-bx^3}{c})^{2}=(\frac{bx}{c})^{3}$

You have to develop this and make the substitution for $x^3$ by $t$. You will get a quadratic equation on $t$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

Comment: yes, raising to the power 6 is a step forward, many thanks, just trying to figure out the rest of it